# Неожиданное поведине AUTOINCREMENT с INSERT IGNORE и UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Проверял на **MySQL 5.7.19** и **MariaDB 10.2.8** результат аналогичный.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `title` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) VALUES (1, 'Title 1');
INSERT IGNORE INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) VALUES (1, 'Title 1');
INSERT IGNORE INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) VALUES (1, 'Title 1');
INSERT IGNORE INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) VALUES (2, 'Title 2');
SELECT * FROM `test`;
```

Вместо ожидаемого:

```
1, 1, Title 1
2, 2, Title 2
```

Получаю:

```
1, 1, Title 1
4, 2, Title 2
```

То есть **INSERT IGNORE**, даже если не вставляет данные, всё равно инкрементирует автоинкремент.

Это документированное поведение?

Почему так?

Что с этим можно сделать, кроме как поместить все **INSERT**-ы в 1 запрос, так оно работает ожидаемо, но не решает очевидную проблему, и конечно же, кроме, как проверять на отсутствие данных перед вставкой отдельным запросом **SELECT**.

P.S. На крайний случай, меня бы даже устроило, если можно было проверку на отсутствие данных и вставку этих данных поместить в 1 запрос, но в первую очередь интересует, почему так вообще происходит и `баг` это или `фича`?

Comment: Видимо https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655448/5441700

Comment: Пока всё печально. :( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0 тоже не выход, так как во-первых это ломает приложение на сервере с настройками по умолчанию, а во-вторых ломает транзакции. :-( Благодарю это ответило на первые 2 моих вопроса.

Comment: Автоинкремент решает единственную задачу - генерацию уникального значения. А на все посторонние хотелки - непрерывность и т.п.,- ему воскласть... если надо - заводим под такого рода ерунду отдельное поле и организуем его заполнение по нужной логике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Да, это `фича` по дизайну [innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes).

2 Потому что **MySQL**.

3 Заменил **IGNORE** этим костылём, имитирующим **WHERE** у **INSERT**.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `title` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
INSERT INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT 1,'Title 1')`s` WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM `test` WHERE `code`=1);
INSERT INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT 1,'Title 1')`s` WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM `test` WHERE `code`=1);
INSERT INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT 1,'Title 1')`s` WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM `test` WHERE `code`=1);
INSERT INTO `test`(`code`,`title`) SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT 2,'Title 2')`s` WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM `test` WHERE `code`=2);
SELECT * FROM `test`;
```